# Websocket problem in Firefox (not in Chrome) in Vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, websocket

Project implies server side (now its Laravel on localhost via docker) and front side - Vue.js.

**Steps I perform:**

1. create new Vue project (use default settings: babel and lint only)
2. install axios
3. add some logic to the Login component

   ```
   <script>

     var axios = require('axios');
     var base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;


       export default {
           name: 'login-component',
           data() {
               return {
                   login: '',
                   password: '',
                   error_message_text: 'Неправильный логин или пароль',
                   error_message_status: false,
                   success_message_text: 'Вы успешно вошли в систему',
                   success_message_status: false,
                   server_response_result: ''
               }
           }
           methods: {

               loginUser() {
                       var vm = this; // axios scope solution

                       axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

                       axios.post( // forming request to the server api
                           'http://localhost:8081/api',
                           {
                               "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                               "method": 'user.login',
                               "params": {
                                   "username": vm.login,
                                   "password": vm.password
                               },
                               "id": 1
                           }
                       ).then(function(response) {
                           if ('result' in response.data) {
                               vm.server_response_result = response.data['result']; // save server result to data


                               if ('token' in response.data.result) {
                                   let token = response.data.result['token'];
                                   vm.$emit('emitAccessToken', token); // if receiced access_token then send it to Vue parent data
                                   vm.encodeAccessToken(token);
                               }
                               vm.success_message_status = true;  // inform user that he has successfully logged in
                           }


                           if ('error' in response.data) {
                               vm.success_message_status = false; // hide success message, if it is displayed
                               vm.error_message_status = true; // show error message
                               vm.$emit('deleteAccessToken'); // delete old access_token from previous login in Vue parent data


                               if ('data' in response.data.error) { // if we have error text from server, then use it, otherwise use default
                                   vm.error_message_text = response.data.error['data'];
                               }else{
                                   vm.error_message_text = 'Неправильный логин или пароль';
                               }
                           }else{
                               vm.error_message_status = false; // if we don't get eny error in response, then hide error area
                           }


                       });
               },
               encodeAccessToken(token){
                  let decodedToken = base64.decode(token);
                  let arr = decodedToken.split('"}');
                   window.console.log(arr);


               }
           }
       }
   </script>


   <style scoped>
     .card{
       max-width:300px;
     }
   </style>
   ```

I didn't place template code, but its there)

4. Create config file and set up proxy

Because backend( : 8080) and frontend( :8081 ) run on different ports, we use vue.config.js file where we specify proxy settings. Based on documentation it's should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
    }
}
```

5. Run dev server for the front

   npm run serve
6. Then I load the frontend in browser http://localhost:8081
   And I can even make the requests to the backend and everything works fine, the browser console display answer from backend. And thanks to sockJS plugin realtime changes works too (browser reacts on the changes I made in IDE)

---

**Next comes the problem part.** 
As soon I refresh the page, obviously something wrong happens to the websocket and the connection of real time editing get lost and every second in browser console appear error messages like this(infinite error cycle):

```
The connection to ws://10.0.75.1:8081/sockjs-node/724/kqxnh5s0/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

The connection to the backend keep working, I still can get respond from it. So it's only infinite error messages in console and lost of real time sync with the browser.

Or if I even not allow to run Network Host by specifying

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
        host: 'localhost'
    }
}
```

The problem stays, but looks different

```
The connection to ws://localhost:8081/sockjs-node/603/3loi0dyu/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

Internet is full with the problem like that, where no one really suggest any solution. It's always suggestions to switch on the Chrome or "It is FF but, which gonna be fixed soon". 
Can anyone suggest something constructive?

Those are the 2 responses which comes every second

[200 response code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1VC.png)

[101 response code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdgW6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after searching for a while and not being able to find the answer. I tihnk you were close, but something you did was little bit different.

What I did to fix the infinite error messages in console, is added this in my vue.config.js. In theory it was only the devServer line, but I'm not sure if that's enough.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/'
      : 'http://localhost:8081/',
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost"
  }
})
```

After restarting the dev-server, it showed both addresses set as "localhost". It's important to set the correct ports, depending on how you are running the app.

```
      App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8081/ 
  - Network: http://localhost:8081/
```